# Python INPUT gives wrong result

Tags: python, user-input

I am trying to enter numbers with input statement, everything is fine, the only problem is when i start the numbers with '0'. It gives wrong result. Can someone explain me what exactly happens and why it gives wrong result.

Here is a small example:

```
 >>> a = input("> ")
 > 12345
 >>> a
 12345
 >>> a = input("> ")
 > 012345
 >>> a
 5349
 >>> print a
 5349
 >>> if a == 012345: print "matched"

 matched
```

I am not understanding this. Thanks for any help! (Windows XP, Python 2.7.3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python 2, starting a number with `0` marks it as octal (base 8).

12345 oct = 5349 dec

Answer (score 2):

In Python, a number that starts with `0` is recognised as in base 8 (octal). You will notice that a number starting with `0` that has an `8` or `9` will raise an exception.

As a side note, you shouldn't use `input()` in Python 2, as it evaluates the input. Use `raw_input()` instead, and then convert that to an `int`. If you want to get rid of the base 8 problem, then pass `10` as the second argument to `int()` (the base):

```
a = raw_input('> ')
try:
    a = int(a, 10)
except ValueError:
    #do something
print a
```

Comment: Custom parser? `int` takes an optional `base` argument. `int('012345', 10) == 12345`

Answer (score 0):

[`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) evaluates whatever is read from the stream - so it is read an a number and returned as an integer.

It sounds like you are looking for [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), which gives whatever was read off the stream as a string

(so `input('> ')` is the same as `eval(raw_input('> '))`)

As [@Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290664/766952) said, the integer value seems unexpected because python is interpreting the value as an octal.